# How can i change color for geom_point in this situation?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, data-visualization

Here is the code:

```
df$ProsperRating..Alpha.<-ordered(df$ProsperRating..Alpha., 
                                  levels = c("AA","A","B","C","D","E","HR"))
ggplot(aes(x=BorrowerAPR,y=LP_InterestandFees),
       data=subset(df,!is.na(ProsperRating..Alpha.)))+
  geom_point(alpha=0.2,aes(color=ProsperRating..Alpha.),position = "jitter")
```

Here is the resulted plot:
[image]

But i need to change the color of the points into blues, like this:
[image]

How can i achieve that ?

Comment: See `scale_color_manual` or `scale_color_discrete`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)

qplot(x, price, data = diamonds, colour = clarity) +
  scale_colour_brewer(palette="Blues", direction = -1)
```

produces this

[image]